# Is storing php array in mysql as serialized harmful?

Tags: php, serialization

I have some data data as array in php and i am storing this as serialized in mysql table in a single column. Does this have any potential harm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "mysql_real_escape_string()" to escape unwanted codes before storing the data in mysql. Also stripslashes() and addslashes() functions are available. These functions escapes special characters in a string so you can store and retrieve the data safely.

Still it may affect the performance to some extent.

Comment: Yeah i do use mysql_real_escape_string always. I feel its better then storing these records in multiple rows in another table to storing all in single column in same table.